# System of differential equations - A depends on t

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm considering the system
$
\begin{cases}
y_1'=y_2+t^4 \\
y_2'=-2/t^2y_1+2/ty_2+t^2
\end{cases}
$
It is easily verified that the matrix $ \begin{bmatrix}
t^2 & t \\
2t & 1
\end{bmatrix}$ is a fundamental matrix (a solution to the homogenous case).
the system can also be written as
$
Y'(t)=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
-2/t^2 & 2/t
\end{bmatrix}
Y'(t)
+
\begin{bmatrix}
t^4 \\
t^2
\end{bmatrix}
$
I want to solve the initial condition $Y(2)=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$. This I can easily do if the matrix does not depend on $t$ but I don't know how to solve it when it depend on $t$ and I cant seem to find any answers on the web.

Comment: I think you have $Y'$ and $Y$ swapped in your "$ \dots +\begin{bmatrix} t^4 \\ t^2 \end{bmatrix}$" equation.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure you're missing a "$y_1$" in your first system.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't upvote this answer.  It does not provide a technique, but stands only as a monument(?) to my surprise that the solution is polynomial...

The solution to your system (or at least the one I think you meant) $$\begin{align*}
    y_1' &= y_2 + t^4 \\
    y_2' &= \frac{-2 y_1 }{ t^2 } + \frac{ 2 y_2 }{ t } + t^2
\end{align*}$$ is $$\begin{align*}
    y_1(t) &= \frac{1}{6} t^4 (t + 1) + t^2 c_1 + t c_2 \\
    y_2(t) &= \frac{-1}{6}(t - 4) t^3 + 2 c_1 t  + c_2, 
\end{align*}$$ where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are arbitrary constants (chosen to match your initial conditions).  With your initial condition, we have  $$\begin{align*}
    1 &= \frac{1}{6} 2^4 (2 + 1) + 2^2 c_1 + 2 c_2 \\
    1 &= \frac{-1}{6}(2 - 4) 2^3 + 2 c_1 2  + c_2, 
\end{align*}$$ which is easily enough solved to $c_1 = 11/12, c_2 = -16/3$.